# VTK outputwindow to file

Tags: python, vtk

How does one send vtk standard error/warning messages to a file?  I'm using Python 2.7 & VTK 5.10.1-3.

I'm using the Iterative Closest Point routine in the VTK package.  Every so often it pops up the standard output window to display an eigenvalue warning.  The warning is of no consequence to me, I just want to send the message to a file so it doesn't pop up the standard output window.  Or how can I just suppress the warnings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calling vtkImageData::GlobalWarningDisplayOff() should take care of it.

Found from: http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Warning-window-td5042996.html